# Universal Analytics: Traffic source from target A in target B reports

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have a few targets: registration, success payment, discard payment, etc. And I need to see traffic source, that was on registration target achieved on all other reports. Is there any way to make this?

Comment: Not sure I quite understand what you are asking for. Do you want to see the channel your visitors used when completing registration etc.? Have you tried adding channels as a second dimension?